# Sudden app shutdown without doing any activity, throws IllegalStateException onMeasure()

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception, application-shutdown

My app **always** shutdown in random time interval (mostly from few minutes to something like 20 mins). The "App stopped working" messagebox appears. Biggest problem is, I don't do anything in app (like interacting with it), and it just random shutdown by itself. Here's logcat print:

```
07-15 20:34:16.595 27361-27363/test.game D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 141
9K, 44% free 13902K/24391K, paused 4ms+9ms, total 66ms
07-15 20:34:28.997 27361-27363/test.game D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1416K, 43% free 13903K/24391K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 56ms
07-15 20:34:29.418 27361-27361/test.game D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-15 20:34:29.418 27361-27361/test.game W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412b52a0)
07-15 20:34:29.498 27361-27361/test.game E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15293)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2397)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15288)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1390)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

One would say, it's because I didn't write `setMeasuredDimension()` when overriding method `onMeasure()`. Also, docs say you have to write this line to your onMeasure, otherwise the IllegalStateException will be thrown ([see it here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29)).

But I don't overriding `onMeasure` anywhere in my whole project, so problem is not here (at least not on my side in this case).

**Few things to note:**

- this is full logcat log, and any of these lines ("*at android.* ...") doesn't link to my code, all goes to source - that means all of these links are gray
- this exception always happens only on my S3 Mini (android 4.1.2), but **never** happened on my old Galaxy Ace S5830i (android 2.3.6) (and yes, I tested it alot - over 20hours on old phone and app still running!).
- never happened in emulator
- there are no "view resizing" operations running in background, which could cause this exception

I would like to post some code, but I have absolutely no idea where this exception could be thrown.

If someone can help, I'd be really, really grateful. I'm lost at this point...

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not code, this is just a random guess. You can start by looking out for activities in which you've added fragments. It might be that the activity containing a fragment has been destroyed on the device due to inactivity for a long time(and memory requirements by the system, which I think is the reason that you are finding the bug on a device and not on the other). So the case is that the fragment might be referring to a view which might not be attached to the window now. (You can also look for views that use fragment adapters like viewPager, etc if you have used them).

Comment: So you think it could cause some, after some time, non-existing view? I have few of them refered as a static View. By the way, I have one viewPager in my app, which I'm refering as static viewPager too.
I'll look on it.

Comment: Seems to be the most likely cause. All the best bro! Such errors are most difficult to find and correct.

Comment: Thanks, but making viewPager non-static didn't helped :( I'll try to reduce more static views in my app, but this was the biggest hope :/